# How to find the details of the devices connected to my hotspot using cmd?

Tags: cmd

I made my windows 10 pc a wifi hotspot using command prompt. It worked succeessfuly and now I want to find who is using my hotspot because it is my right. I can find only the number of devices connected to it. Now I want to find the ip address mac address and other details about the devices connected to my hotspot. But remember I don't like to use any software. I want to do it using only my command promt. If there is a way, please help me!!

Comment: You don't want to do fake public wifi for malicious activities, right?

Comment: It is not for malicious activities.I don't have a wifi router but I want to connect to internet using my smart phone. That's why I make my laprop a wifi hotspot.

Comment: Where do you see `hostednetwork status`? What program do you run to see this?

Comment: I'm not using a programme. I use "netsh wlan show hostednetwork" to see hostednetwork status.